# Creating a navigation - inline-block or float?

Tags: html, navigation, html-lists, css-float, css

When I try to create a navigation with inline-block, I get 4px to the right of each list item.

When I do it by floating each list item, it works fine.

Is there a reason the first option is applying that 4px? I have set EVERYTHING to have a margin of 0px and padding of 0px, I don't understand it. Even Firebug reports it as having 0, yet the gap is still there.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a code snippet for a better answer

Comment: @mmanco: No need for that. Check my answer and especially the linked JSFiddle, where you can see the effect of *spacing*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, space is by design and should be

Is there a reason for that? Yes it is. What got added is actually a **word space**. The same as if you'd have two lines of text. Browsers put a space between texts in separate lines so last words don't touch first words of the next line:

```
<p>
  This is my text that's in two lines
  inside my HTML source.
</p>
```

There would be a usual word space between *lines* and *inside* so text gets correctly displayed in browser:

> This is my text that's in two lines inside my HTML source.

The same happens in your case, because your elements are inline. Your navigation elements are listed one per line in HTML source hence a word break gets added between them.

### How to avoid excessive spaces between elements?

There are basically 3 approaches to mitigate this *problem*. All of them work on the premise to put all elements in the same line as seen by the HTML renderer:

1. **Put all elements unspaced in a single line**:

   ```
   <ul>
       <li>First</li><li>Second</li>...<li>Last</li>
   </ul>
   ```

   This one actually puts all elements in one line which may make it harder for people to manipulate these elements. If every `LI` would have an anchor tag inside (with a long link), this line gets too long to handle.
2. **Comment-out line breaks**:

   ```
   <ul><!--
       --><li>First</li><!--
       --><li>Second</li><!--
       ...
       --><li>Last</li><!--
   --></ul>
   ```
3. **Make tags break the line**:

   ```
   <ul
      ><li>First</li
      ><li>Second</li
       ...
      ><li>Last</li
   ></ul>
   ```

   This one is least obtrusive to the eye but may seem confusing to beginners hence other team members (if you work in such environment) may feel tempted to put tag ends back to where they were originally (and usually are). They may feel these were broken by error.

The result of all three of them can be seen in [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cxbqN/1).

Pick the one that suits you best. I usually use commenting because it's least distracting in my development editor because comments are very subtle.

Comment: There's one more approach: omit `li`'s closing tags. Although it may be considered bad practice, it is safe in all browsers and valid in every HTML spec.

Comment: @duri: but invalid if you're using XHTML. But OP didn't explicitly say they're using `LI`. I just used them because it's common to use them these days.